# Authorizing users of ANY organization with OAuth

Tags: oauth, dynamics-crm

I am trying to authorize my app to access the Microsoft Dynamics 365 API on behalf of users from many different organizations.

I am already familiar with the OAuth auth flow, but I don't really understand the 'resource' parameter.

It says "The App ID URI of the web API (secured resource)." and it looks like I need to use the specific root service address of the user, like "https://thisuser.crm.dynamics.com", but there's no way for me to know this URL, so how do I authorize users in general without knowing their resource URI?

Comment: Are you able to recieve an OAuth bearer token? What method are you using to authenticate the users?

Comment: @Kenci : I can't get a token because I need the resource URI in order to make the request. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-protocols-oauth-code
My question is how do I get the resource URI of a user for which I am authenticating?

Comment: What do you mens the app is supposed to access dynamics CRM on behalf of users from different organizations? Do you want to access the API of a users organisation, or do you have 1 "central" API which the users are supposed to access ?

Comment: @Kenci I have my own application, and I want to give Dynamics CRM users the ability to authorize me through OAuth to make changes in their Dynamics account to sync data from my applications to Dynamics.
I am not sure if I can just use 1 dynamics API for all users and just have different credentials, or if I need to use a different API for each user. 
I have experience with the Salesforce CRM and their OAuth flow, and with them I don't have to specify a URI, as it is provided to me after the flow is complete, which is how I know which API URL to use for the requests specific to that user.

Comment: In Azure you need to make an "App registration" in the Active Directory, and add permissions to that App, so that its allowed to access a Dynamics 365 API. This requires the App and the CRM instance to be in the same Active Directory. Im guessing this is not possible in your case, as the CRM instances/Web API's you want to access are not in your Active Directory, but are in the AD's of the users organizations ?

Comment: Se the answer by Colin Vermander: https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/117/t/212493